# How to stop android Mx Player on back pressed

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I have a code which display video via mx player when i start app first time it works wituout any error but if i close and open app again it says activity mx player is not responding.How can i close the mx player when i press back button.
my code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startMxPlayer(1, 1);
    finish();
}


private void startMxPlayer(int tuner, int ch) { 
    int port = 8000 + tuner * 10 + ch; 
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("udp://224.1." + (port & 0xff) + ".1:" + port); 
    Log.v("server", "udp://224.1." + (port & 0xff) + ".1:" + port); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
    intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" );
    intent.putExtra("end_by","user");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); 
    getApplication().startActivity(intent); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can possibly stop to kill the process but i would suggest you to do in other way.

```
private void startMxPlayer(int tuner, int ch) { 
int port = 8000 + tuner * 10 + ch; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("udp://224.1." + (port & 0xff) + ".1:" + port); 
Log.v("server", "udp://224.1." + (port & 0xff) + ".1:" + port); 

// add the following line.
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" );
intent.putExtra("end_by","user");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); 
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```